# iOS Xcode: Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSlimDeviceTypeiPdad2x error after updating to Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios12

I am developing React Native app using `react-native-cli`.

To run iOS app on device with `iOS 12.2` installed i've recently updated my Xcode version to 10.2 and I am facing this error during the compilation:

[image]

Also, getting this error, trying to open simulator from Xcode - Open developer tool
[image]

What can be the problem?

Comment: There is no Xcode 12.2 yet!

Comment: @AshishKakkad It is. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_release_notes/ios_12_2_release_notes

Comment: It's iOS 12.2 not Xcode 12.2 - Xcode version is 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 10.2 which contains iOS 12.2 and it's simulators

Please go to **Xcode > Preferences > Locations**

[image: XPref]

Select command line tools to latest Xcode.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command to make sure all background process of the simulator that were run during the update are killed :

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```